# Dependency injection in object hierarchy

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependency-injection, interface

I've a class diagram like this:

```
       TopClass
       ◆     ◆
       |      |
  SubClass1   SubClass2
  ◆      ◆
  |       |
  |       ChildClass2
  |
  ChildClass1
```

`TopClass` has `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`.
`Subclass1` has `ChildClass1` and `ChildClass2`.

I use dependency injection on each of these classes. So when `ChildClass1` needs interface `X` I need to pass `X` thru `TopClass` and `Subclass1`. When `ChildClass2` needs `Y` I also need to pass it thru whole hierarchy. Eventually I end up with `TopClass` full of dependencies to interfaces it actually doesn't use. I find it smelly.

I've found an [article about facade pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) which seemd promising but eventually I cannot find a way to use it in my situation.

Any other idea? And I wouldn't like to use singleton or any similar solution as I need to be able to unit tests these classes easily.

**EDIT**

Another option which I just found and which I'm going to test for a while is boost.DI:

http://boost-experimental.github.io/di/cpp-london-2017

http://boost-experimental.github.io/di/

Comment: why you need to pass interface thru whole hierarchy ?

Comment: @dstar55: in most cases object implementing particular interface is kind of singleton at the top level (like object responsible for reading/writing config, logging, database accessor etc) so I want one object to be passed everywhere. From the other side you may be right, and some of the dependencies are passed around unnecessarily.

Comment: if you want one object to be passed maybe you can consider Bridge pattern, http://www.design-patterns-stories.com/patterns/Bridge/, where abstraction is separated from implementation.

Comment: @dstar55 I don't understand how the Bridge pattern would help.  It doesn't eliminate the dependencies that each child class has, so the original problem of the parent class needing a bunch of dependencies to ultimately pass to its children still remains.

Comment: @Ben, I do not have full picture, therefore I said: maybe you can consider Bridge. What are those dependencies which need to be injected ? Maybe dependencies can be injected in implementation of the Bridge, just as idea.

Comment: @dstar55 I can't speak for @MichalWalenciak, but in my similar situations, the dependencies are common utility-type things like `FileService`, `DateTimeService`, `ConfigurationService`, `LogService`, and so on.  They are common environment-type things which most business logic services have dependencies on.

Comment: @dstar55 In the past, I've considered creating an `EnvironmentService` which is facade on top of those common services, but I decided against it because it seems like a lot of work just for the result of hiding several services behind another service.

Comment: @Ben, inject common utilities in service layer is OK, for example typical DB app design will have model, dao layer, service layer and in principle you are injecting dependencies in dao layer(db connection) and in service layer(dao's), but model has no dependencies to inject(only annotations), therefore I claimed that it is hard to give proper answer without full picture

Comment: @dstar55: As far as I understand how does bridge works - I already use it. I'm not passing particular implementation down but rather I use abstract interfaces. That's quite clear I think. My problem is similar to Ben's - I just need to pass all my services down thru class hierarchy and I find it messy (especialy when project grows and main class needs to pass more and more interfaces down)

Comment: @BenRubin: what now comes to my mind is to pass abstract factory for producing group of similar (related) interfaces. So that would group a few interfaces into one. It somehow clears the situation I think. Yet I'm not sure if I see all drawbacks of such solution.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak Your idea is one of things I've considered in the past too.  I'm not necessarily against it, but the thing that's stopped me from going that route in the past is that I think it has a Service Locator smell to it.  I suppose if you passed several child factories into your parent factory, and then passed your parent factory into your `TopClass`, then each `ChildClass` could use that parent factory to create its dependencies, and you'd mitigate the Service Locator smell somewhat because you're passing child factories into your parent factory as dependencies.

Comment: @MichałWalenciak I've been looking for a good solution to this for years and I still haven't been able to figure out a solution that doesn't have drawbacks.  I hope we can get a good answer to this.